# Getting error while viewing files in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded some files from my local cmd prompt onto Azure Blob Storage which can be seen over there, however on console I cannot view them and the below error appears. I am login with my admin credentials. Need assistance.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error when I authenticated using Microsoft Entra ID Authentication.

**Portal:**

[image]

The error above occurred because you do not have permission to access the storage account.

To access storage using Microsoft Entra ID authentication, the user needs the [**Storage Blob Data Contributor**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles/storage#storage-blob-data-contributor) role.

You can also access the storage account using an access key.

[image]

For that, you need to click the switch to access the key.

Ensure that you have enabled "Allow storage account key access" in your configuration.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Authorize access to blobs using Microsoft Entra ID - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Yes solved the issue. Thanks